# How to disable scrolling the document body?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xhtml

I have a HTML which has lot of content and a vertical scrollbar appears as soon as the HTML is loaded. Now from this HTML a full screen IFRAME is loaded. The problem is when the IFRAME is loaded, the parent scrollbar still persists, I want to disable the scrollbar when the Iframe is loaded.

I tried:

- `document.body.scroll = "no"`, it did not work with FF and chrome.
- `document.style.overflow = "hidden";` after this I was still able to scroll, and the whole iframe would scroll up revealing the parent HTML.

My requirement is, when the IFRAME is loaded, we should never be able to scroll the entire IFRAME if the parent HTML has a scrollbar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you want to use the iframe's scrollbar and not the parent's use this:

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

If you want to use the parent's scrollbar and not the iframe's then you need to use:

```
document.getElementById('your_iframes_id').scrolling = 'no';
```

or set the `scrolling="no"` attribute in your iframe's tag: `<iframe src="some_url" scrolling="no">`.

Comment: Except please do this in a stylesheet and not in Javascript :-)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I was doing it wrong, it works as explained.

Answer (score 17):

with css

```
body, html {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is `body, html {` and not just plain `body {`?

Answer (score 9):

The following JavaScript could work:

```
var page = $doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

To disable Scroll use:

```
page.classList.add('noscroll');
```

To enable Scroll use:

```
page.classList.remove('noscroll');
```

In the CSS file, add:

```
.noscroll {
    position: fixed!important
}
```

Comment: position:fixed; was the solution in my case

Comment: Note that when using position: fixed, the scroll position of the body will move to the top which may be disconcerting

Comment: nice solution, make sure to set body width to 100% otherwise the body will be collapsed.

Answer (score 3):

add this css

```
body.disable-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and when to disable run this code

```
$("body").addClass("disable-scroll");
```

and when to enabled run this code

```
$("body").removeClass("disable-scroll")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an ancient question, but I just thought that I'd weigh in.

I'm using [disableScroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/disable-scroll). Simple and it works like in a dream.

I have had some trouble disabling scroll on body, but allowing it on child elements (like a modal or a sidebar). It looks like that something can be done using `disableScroll.on([element], [options]);`, but I haven't gotten that to work just yet.

---

The reason that this is prefered compared to `overflow: hidden;` on body is that the overflow-hidden can get nasty, since some things might add `overflow: hidden;` like this:

... This is good for preloaders and such, since that is rendered before the CSS is finished loading.

But it gives problems, when an open navigation should add a class to the `body`-tag (like `<body class="body__nav-open">`). And then it turns into one big tug-of-war with `overflow: hidden; !important` and all kinds of crap.

Answer (score -3):

Answer :
document.body.scroll = 'no';

Comment: This only works for IE and so is not recommended for a project.